# Regular expression - Contain at most 1 occurrence of substring

Tags: regex

I want a regular expression for finding at most one occurrence of the substring bab. (in the alphabeth {a,b})

Here I have a regular expression for finding bb at most in Alphabeth {a,b}

```
(a+ba)* + (a+ba)*.b + (a+ba)*.bb.(a+ab)*
```

I want to use this example regex but then use bab as the substring. 
How can I expand this regex for finding at most one occurrence of the substring bab?

Am I starting right with this:

```
(b+ab)* + (b+ab)*b + (a+ba)* + (a+ba)*.b + (a+ba)*.bab.(a+ab)*
```

Comment: Your regex syntax isn't right. Perhaps you've mixed it with logic syntax?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. Can you clarify your question, intent, expectations?

Comment: if I understand your question,  if you want the regex to return after the first match, just do not use the global filter. See: https://regex101.com/r/bZG3lN/1

Comment: Made an edit to the description. @Khanna111 No for example a or b or aa etc is accepted. At most it can have the substring bab. So, aaababaaabab is not accepted

Comment: @MeesvanZ plz. check the answer.

Comment: You really need to post list of examples: what you probably can have in string and strings that match your request, for example:
aaababaaaaaa - that surely is true
aaababaababaaa - that is false
aaabababaaaaa - but that is not clear

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question, you want to match strings that only have at most one count of "bab" and if there are more than one then do not match.

We can use negative lookaheads for this:

https://regex101.com/r/QBe2bD/3

I used the test strings that galabra posted as a starting point.

Note: "`babab`" matches. If you do not want to match that, you could use an alternate but I leave that as an exercise.

Hint: `^(?!.*bab(.*bab|--)).*$`
Replace the "--" with two characters that will allow you to not match babab.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I have to say this was much more complicated than I thought, and took some time to solve. Certainly a great question!

The following diagram (made with [draw.io](http://draw.io)) illustrates the regular expressions below:

[image: States diagram for the regular expressions]

> The blue circles represent the possible starting points and the red ones mark where the string can terminate.

As for the regular expressions:

1. [The following regex](https://regex101.com/r/ETVoud/2) embodies the diagram exactly as it's written:

   ```
   ^a*(b+(aa+)*)*bab((a(a+(b+)*)*)*|b+(aa*)*)$
   ```
2. Where [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/ETVoud/3) is equivalent, but simplified and well-ordered:

   ```
   ^a*(?:b+(?:a{2,})*)*bab(?:(?:a(?:a+b*)*)*|b+a*)$
   ```

Comment: Did you use any tool for making the diagram?

Comment: I dont get this regex to work... For example in this tool: http://ivanzuzak.info/noam/webapps/fsm2regex/

Comment: @MeesvanZ What are you trying to achieve with this platform?